# Youtube-dl - Playlist download - Is it possible to skip videos that contain a specific word?

Tags: youtube-dl

I am trying to download a very long playlist, about 500+ vods, from twitch. I would like to skip certain files that contain a specific word in the title. If its possible, how?

Answer (score 3):

Yes.

```
--reject-title
```

U can use string or regex.

Another, more expanded option is

```
--match-filter
```

type youtube-dl -h sometimes